# Какое значение у слова «но» в предложении «Фенечке нравился Базаров; но и она ему нравилась» из романа «Отцы и дети» И. С. Тургенева?

Tags: пунктуация, значение-слов, союзы, литература

> Фенечке нравился Базаров; **но** и она ему нравилась. Даже лицо его изменялось, когда он с ней разговаривал: оно принимало выражение ясное, почти доброе, и к обычной его небрежности примешивалась какая-то шутливая внимательность.
>
> *И. С. Тургенев «Отцы и дети»*

«Но» — это противительный союз, т. е. союз выражающий противопоставление.

Однако в данном предложении противопоставления нет, а как раз наоборот указывается на совпадение чувств. Тут уместней был бы сочинительный союз «и»:

*Фенечке нравился Базаров; **и** она ему нравилась.*

---

Возможно, оказывает влияние точка с запятой, но и почему поставлена точка с запятой не ясно.

---

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Пользователь grizzly в своём ответе утверждает, что «но и» в данном случае союзное сочетание, однако не удаётся найти какого-то источника, где «но и» было бы отнесено к союзным сочетаниям.

Пытаясь проверить версию grizzly, я нашёл «но и» среди градационных союзов. Точнее нашёл «но и», как вторую часть градационного союза.

Пользователь Jim Korbett так же в своём ответе называет «но и» соединительно-градационным союзом.

Я склоняюсь к мысли, что это всё-таки в данном случае градационный союз, но есть некоторые вопросы.

---

Вероятно, это предложение построено на основе градационного союза, но с опусканием его первой части:

*[**Не только**] Фенечке нравился Базаров; **но и** она ему нравилась.*

В таком виде предложение имеет смысл.

---

> **Градационные союзы**
> Главным образом сопоставительные союзы при однородных членах: оба компонента этих союзов находятся в разных частях предложения, причем вторая часть имеет большую смысловую нагрузку по сравнению с первой.
> *Не только .. но и, не столько .. сколько, не так... как, не то что ..но (а), не то чтобы .. но (а), если не .. то* и др.
> Некоторые исследователи присоединяют к ним сложные союзы
> *да и, а то и, а не то и* и др.
>
> *[[Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов. Розенталь Д. Э., Теленкова М. А.](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/287/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)]*

---

**Не понятно следующее:**

По смыслу рассмотрение «но и» как градационного союза хорошо подходит, потому что тут есть сопоставление, и вторая часть предложения имеет большую смысловую нагрузку по сравнению с первой.

Однако в первой части «не только» всё-таки нет. Можно ли считать «но и» градационным союзом без неё?

Правда, у Розенталя есть оговорка:

> Некоторые исследователи присоединяют к ним сложные союзы
> *да и, а то и, а не то и* и др.

Значит, вероятно, можно считать «но и» градационным союзом без первой части. Но твёрдой уверенности нет.

---

**По поводу точки с запятой:**

Пользователь grizzly в своём ответе даёт правдоподобное объяснение:

> Что касается точки запятой, то на этот вопрос нельзя ответить, не познакомившись с контекстом. Фенечке нравился Базаров подытоживает текст предыдущего абзаца, а далее поясняется, что и она нравилась Базарову. Точка с запятой разделяет этот переход.

Однако это объяснение не подкреплено никакими правилами использования точки с запятой.

Под какое правило можно подвести использование точки с запятой в данном случае, исходя из объяснения grizzly, или исходя из какого бы то ни было другого объяснения?

---

Интересный пример привёл в своём ответе Jim Korbett:

> Я виноват, я вам солгал; но и Гринев вас обманывает. (Соединительно-градационный союз «но и».)

Это из Кпитанской дочки А. С. Пушкина:

> — Государь! — закричал он в исступлении. — **Я виноват, я вам солгал; но и Гринев вас обманывает.** Эта девушка не племянница здешнего попа: она дочь Ивана Миронова, который казнен при взятии здешней крепости.

Видно, что тут та же самая конструкция предложения с «но и» и точкой с запятой.

Может быть, есть какое-то общее правило? Может эта точка с запятой, как раз и ставится из-за отсутствия первой части градационного союза? Может точка с запятой создаёт большую паузу (как заметил в своём ответе Ivan Olshansky), чем запятая, давая понять, что тут «градационные» отношения между частями предложения, а не простое противопоставление?

Comment: *Eagle*, я подсократила ваш заголовок, такой длиннющий. Оставила самое главное. Если против — можете откатить.

Comment: Если бы вместо точки с запятой стояла запятая, я бы тоже счел версию с градационным союзом предпочтительной. Но точка с запятой заставляет меня склоняться к тому варианту, который я описал ранее. Кстати, обязательно прочтите ответ @Sharon: лично я проголосовал за него, т.к. на мой взгляд он логично дополняет и расширяет мой ответ.

Comment: Тогда было бы: *[Не только] Фенечке нравился Базаров; но и **кому-то другому**.* То есть "не только" относится к следующему слову.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я вам благодарен за проявленную заботу, однако в списке вопросов виден только заголовок, и в сокращённом виде он малоинформативен. К тому же, я думаю, что в более полном виде мой вопрос будет лучше находиться в Интернете через поисковые системы. Может, кто-то будет искать в Интернете и найдёт мой вопрос.

Comment: @oleedd Возможно, чтоб не было такого неправильного понимания, там и не стоит первая часть сопоставительного союза. Тут смысл в том, что чувства между ними были взаимны, а не безответны: не только X любил Y, но и Y любил X. Ведь может быть так:  X любил Y, но Y не любил X. Цель сопоставления посредством союза «но и» показать взаимность чувств, которая не совсем ожидаема.

Comment: @Eagle Не думаю, что в составных союзах может опускаться какая-то часть. Не возьмусь обобщать про все, но это точно не про "не только ... но и". Между ними связь такая сильная, что точка с запятой, как и длительная пауза, никак не подходит. Отнесение "не только" не лишь к следующему слову, а ко всему простому предложению — это как-то не по-русски. Это ещё кое-как возможно, если об этом факте уже было известно. *Не только {Фенечке нравился Базаров}* — звучит так, что это уже не новость, но стилистика очень разговорная (плохая), так люди не говорят.

Answer (score 3):

Противопоставление здесь есть, но это не противопоставление написанному, а противопоставление ожидаемому.
В большинстве случаев, когда хотят рассказать об одинаковых чувствах двух героев, в предложении их стараются расположить также максимально одинаково. Например, делают подлежащими в начале фразы:

> Фенечка и Базаров нравились друг другу.

Если же хотят показать отличие чувств, используют ту или иную форму противопоставления, которая видна с самого начала:

> Фенечке нравился Базаров, **а она ему нет**.

Именно чего-то подобного ожидает читатель, прочитавший начало предложения:

> Фенечке нравился Базаров; [*а теперь будет что-нибудь на тему не взаимности*]

Союз "но" здесь используется не для противопоставления первой части фразы, а для противопоставления **ожиданиям читателя**.

Более примитивные аналоги этого приема иногда применяются и в современном творчестве:

> Его первая жена была блондинкой, а вторая... тоже блондинкой.

Чтобы подобные приемы работали, необходимо заставить читателя сделать паузу после первой части предложения, чтобы он успел "додумать" его возможное развитие. Иначе противопоставление не получится.
В примере с Базаровым для создания такой паузы используется точка с запятой, в последнем примере - многоточие.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос новыми мыслями после слова «**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**».

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет никакого противопоставления. Я не верю, что носитель русского языка, пусть даже никогда не изучавший грамматику, сможет произнести что-то типа:

> Она ему нравилась, но и он ей не нравился.

Всё объясняется очень просто: здесь используется не противительный союз **но**, а союзное сочетание **но и**, при помощи которого обычно передаётся присоединительное значение второй части предложения.

Что касается точки запятой, то на этот вопрос нельзя ответить, не познакомившись с контекстом. *Фенечке нравился Базаров* подытоживает текст предыдущего абзаца, а далее поясняется, что и она нравилась Базарову. Точка с запятой разделяет этот переход.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я проголосовал. По точку с запятой мысль интересная. Может быть и так. Хотя хотелсь бы найти какое-то подходящее правило.

Comment: Насчёт того, что никакого противопосталения нет, я так не думаю. «Но» имеет значание, даже если оно входит в состав, как вы считаете, союзного сочетания. Я сейчас уже полагаю, что это составной союз. В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F): _«союзные сочетания — словосочетания, играющие роль союзов, но официально составными союзами не признанные»_. А «но и» всё таки есть в спиках составных союзов.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос новыми мыслями после слова «**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**».

Answer (score 2):

Противительные союзы(там есть союзы, которые следовало бы отнести в разные подсовокупности, но речь о большинстве) не обозначают противопоставление.
Противительные союзы ставятся перед суждением, которое ослабляет или невелирует в некотором отношении предполагаемое общее впечатление или вывод после предшествующего суждения. Взгляните на примеры:
Вступление у игры простое, но интригующее. (После слова ‟простое” у человека возникает негативное общее представление, но следующее после ‟но” суждение его ослабляет в некотором отношении.)
Маленький, но удаленький. (После слова ‟маленький” возникает негативное впечатление или вывод, но следующее суждение его ослабляет или даже невелирует.)
Он плохой служащий, но хороший отец. (После сочетания ‟плохой отец” возникает негативное впечатление или вывод, но следующее суждение его ослабляет или даже невелирует.)

Но в вашем предложении не противительный союз ‟но”, а соединительно-градационный союз ‟но и”. Взгляните на примеры:
Он был не только сильным, но и добрым. (Соединительно-градационный союз ‟не только... но и”.)
Я виноват, я вам солгал; но и Гринев вас обманывает.
(Соединительно-градационный союз ‟но и”.)

Короче, я устал и больше не хочу писать и обдумывать этот ответ, — возможно, куму-то эта незаконченная версия будет полезна.
**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**
Чтобы понять разницу между союзами ‟но” и ‟но и” взгляните на следующие пары предложений:
‟Мой учитель был профессионалом, но я был лентяем” и ‟Мой учитель был профессионалом, но и я был хорошим учеником”;
‟Работы было много, но сил было мало” и ‟Работы было много, но и сил было много”.
‟Она любила фильмы ужасов, но и я их любил” и ‟Она любила  фильмы ужасов, но я их не любил”.
Как вы могли заметить, разница между использованием союзов ‟но” и ‟но и” в том, что в предложении после ‟но и”, о ком-то говорится то же самое(или очень схожее), что и о ком-то говорилось в предшествующем предложении.
Но в целом, эти оба союза являются противительными, то есть ставятся перед суждением, которое ослабляет или невелирует в некотором отношении предполагаемое общее впечатление или вывод после предшествующего суждения.
Вот примеры с разъяснением противительного характера союза ‟но и”:
Мой учитель был профессионалом, но и я был хорошим учеником. (После первого предложения создается впечатление, что нынешний успех человека есть результат только мастерства его учителя, но предложение после ‟но и” ослабляет это впечатление.)
Работы было много, но и сил было много. (То, что работы было много, ослабляется тем, что есть много сил.)
Ты ошибся, но и самые мудрые ошибаются. (Вывод о том, что плохо то, что человек ошибся, ослабляется тем, что никто не безошибочен.)
Я виноват, я вам солгал; но и Гринев вас обманывает. (Ложь человека ослабляется или даже невелируется предложением после ‟но и”.)
Итак, ‟но и” определенно противительный союз; но остается вопрос: как быть с предложениями, как: ‟Фенечке нравился Базаров; но и она ему нравилась” и ‟Она любила фильмы ужасов, но и я их любил”? В таких предложениях, на первый взгляд, нет никаких, даже тонких противопоставительных эманаций.

**ПРО ТОЧКУ С ЗАПЯТОЙ**
Если посмотреть тексты классиков, то там этой точки с запятой после ‟но” очень много. У Пушкина так прямо каждый второй знак перед ‟но” это точка с запятой. Не думаю, что эта точка с запятой связанна с этим случаем с ‟но и”. Понятно, что это какая-то пауза, но существуют 100500 по-разному произносимых пауз. Такие вещи, как паузы, нельзя передать словами, не создав и не согласовав отчетливую терминологию. Ведь нельзя передать звучание иностранного звука, если вы уже не знаете очень похожий звук в своем языке. Единственный способ передавать паузы на письме — это согласовать термины, позволив другим где-то услышать эти произношения.
Может быть, потом допишу ответ.

Comment: Я проголосовал за ваш ответ. Первую часть, я не понял зачем вы наисали. А вторая имеет отношение к делу. Я тоже нашёт «но и» в соединительно-градационных союзах, но пока не понимаю, что это за такой тип союзов. Там где «не только — но и» смысл понятен. В приведенном мной предложении «не только» нет. А вот второй ваш пример похож: «Я виноват, я вам солгал; но и Гринев вас обманывает». И даже точка с запятой стоит. А что вы думаете про точку с запятой?

Comment: Может быть, допишу ответ и доразберусь завтра или послезавтра.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос новыми мыслями после слова «**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**».

Answer (score 2):

1. Как известно, Базаров был **«великий охотник до женщин и до женской красоты**, но любовь в смысле идеальном... называл белибердой, непростительной дурью».  «Нравится тебе женщина..., старайся добиться толку; а нельзя – ну,  и не надо, отвернись – земля не клином сошлась».   Да только далеко не так получилось всё в его жизни…
2. **Хорошенькую Фенечку он приметил сразу**, еще в начале романа. Базаров умел расположить к себе простых людей, вот и Фенечка сразу почувствовала к нему доверие, даже ее малыш охотно пошел на руки «к дохтуру». И вот тогда бы здесь не было союза НО: ***Фенечке нравился Базаров; и она ему нравилась.***  Да и почему бы ей ему не нравиться – хорошенькая ведь!
3. **Но затем в его жизни всё получилось иначе,** и произошла вот такая, к примеру, сцена. Базаров с каким-то озлоблением произносит, отвернувшись к окну: «...Я люблю вас, глупо, безумно...» Он «уперся лбом в стекло окна», стараясь сдержать желание броситься к Анне Сергеевне.

Хотел Базаров уйти с головой в работу, но любовь не забывалась – она будто  что-то изменила в его натуре, надломила его, лишила уверенности и силы.

4. **А как же Фенечка?**  А Фенечка еще похорошела, расцвела, как летняя роза. Её юная  красота очищала душу,  заставляла забыть все темные страсти и метания. Ну и она чувствовала себя при нем всё вольнее и увереннее.

И вот теперь Тургенев записывает: ***Фенечке нравился Базаров; но и она ему нравилась*** (точка с запятой – это пауза для читателя, элемент неожиданности).

5. **А теперь ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

НО И – это союзное соединение.

**Противительный союз НО** здесь главный, а союз И обозначает соответствие ситуаций. Он на втором месте, используется в значении ТОЖЕ (соединительно-отождествительное значение).

По грамматике это **противительно-уступительное значение союза НО**: ситуация второй части противоречит  ожидаемому (естественному) следствию части первой.

**Для справок (частные значения союза НО)**

(1)Противительно ограничительное ( = только): Он хотел встать, но ноги не слушались его.

(2) Противительно-уступительное (но, однако):Его имя Вернер, но он русский.

(3) Противительно-возместительное (зато): У него трудный характер, но он хороший специалист.

(4) Градационное (не что чтобы...но): Сейчас не то чтобы холодно, но очень ветрено.

6. **Так в чем же здесь противоречие и несоответствие ожидаемому?**

Увы, да!  Страдающему от неразделенной любви Базарову **по-прежнему нравится** эта хорошенькая молодая девушка. Вот какой видит ее наш герой: «Одетая в легкое белое платье, она сама казалась белее и легче; загар не приставал к ней, а жара, от которой она не могла уберечься, слегка румянила ее щеки да уши».

Может быть, даже **еще больше нравится**, чем нравилась раньше, потому что  привлекает своей чистотой, как бы излечивает душевные раны.

Comment: Да это не моя классификация, из вузовского учебника стр. 226  Хотите передать автору свой отзыв? https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: Ну вот, а где же комментарий? Jim Korbett!  Ну кто так делает!

Comment: Я не очень хотел спорить, но ладно, поспорю. Классификация — говно! Какая-то обезьяна написала её.

Comment: Например, противительно-ограничительные и противительно-уступительные союзы могут заменять друг друга. Он хотел встать, но ноги не слушались его. (Союз ‟однако” здесь также подходит, хотя он не из этой подсовокупности.). Где противительный союз ‟хотя”? Его забыли? Союз ‟однако” также подходит и в третью подсовокупность — противительно-возместительную.

Comment: Еще союз да(= но) забыли. Эта классификация бессмысленная, нерабочая, с пропущенными союзами, с кучей ошибок. 4-я подсовокупность — это не градационные отношения.

Comment: Надо же по каким плохим учебникам студентов учат, вам непременно  нужно в министерство обратиться по этому вопросу. А ко мне лично вопросы есть?  К сожалению, я так и не смогла найти  в ваших записях ответ на вопрос "Какое значение у слова «но» в предложении из романа «Отцы и дети»?" Вы не могли бы выделить его жирным шрифтом?

Comment: Простите, не поняла...

Comment: Его там нет. Я пока не знаю.

Comment: По первому пункту. Я бы не назвал Базарова большим ловеласом. Что Фенечка, что Одинцова были обожаемы не только Базаровым. У Фенечки было как минимум три поклонника Николая Петрович, Павел Петрович и Базаров. У Одинцовой и Базаров, и Аркадий, но помимо них, а как я понял из содержания, она была интересна для многих. И по содержанию у Базарова, кроме поцелуя с Фенечкой и признания Одинцовой, ничего большего не было. «Великие охотники до женщин» обычно имеют гораздо более большой и серьезный список «достижений» на этом поприще.

Comment: По четвёртому пункту. «Точка с запятой – это пауза для читателя, элемент неожиданности», — возможно. Есть где-то описанное правило такого использования точки с запятой? Как читатель должен догадаться чего хочет сказать автор точкой с запятой? Читатель может это понять только если есть общепринятое правило. Но я такого правила не встречал, хотя может оно где-то и есть. А у Пушкина? Тоже «пауза для читателя, элемент неожиданности»?

Comment: _«По грамматике это противительно-уступительное значение союза НО: ситуация второй части противоречит ожидаемому (естественному) следствию части первой»._ Почему же противоречит? В чём же здесь «уступительный» смысл? Тут же нет такого смыла: *«Фенечке нравился Базаров; **несмотря на то, что** она ему нравилась»* или *«Фенечке нравился Базаров; **вопреки тому, что** она ему нравилась»*. Объяснение в пункте 6 мне не совсем понятно применительно к этому предложению. Хотя, может, в этом что-то и есть.

Comment: В целом, спасибо за ответ. Я всё-таки склоняюсь к мысли, что здесь противительно-градационные отношения. В приведённом вами учебнике: _«Противительно-градационное ... Один из противопоставляемых фактов осознается  говорящим как более важный...»_. В этом предложении главное то, что Базарову тоже нравилась Фенечка. О его чувствах идёт дальнейшее повествование после этого предложения, а до этого предложения речь шла о чувствах Фенечки. Это предложение — переход в повествовании от её чувств к его чувствам, и акцент делается именно на его чувствах.

Answer (score 2):

В целом спасибо за ваше внимание, но голосовать за мой ответ вы не стали, в отличие от всех других ответов, и я это воспринимаю **как его подчеркнуто отрицательную оценку.** Убирать ответ я не буду (пусть остается памятником иного мнения), но добавлю следующее. Надо больше доверять **общепринятым терминам, а не только частным мнениям на эту тему.**

1. **ГРАДАЦИЯ**, -и; ж. [лат. gradatio] Книжн. Последовательность, постепенность в расположении чего-л. при переходе от одного к другому (с усилением или ослаблением проявления какого-л. признака, действия); разделение какого-л. процесса на ступени, стадии, этапы
2. **ГРАДАЦИОННЫЕ СОЮЗЫ** (словарь лингвистических терминов. 2012)
   Главным образом сопоставительные союзы при однородных членах: оба компонента этих союзов находятся в разных частях предложения, причем **вторая часть имеет большую смысловую нагрузку** по сравнению с первой. *Не только... но и, не столько... сколько, не так... как, не то что... но (а), не то чтобы... но (а), если не... то* и др. Некоторые исследователи присоединяют к ним сложные союзы *да и, а то и, а не то и* и др.
3. **Русская грамматика (двойные и градационные союзы)**
   [http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#32](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#32)

Двойные союзы объединены общей семантикой. Они предполагают, что **вторая часть** утверждения, вводимая второй частью союза, с точки зрения Говорящего, **НЕОЖИДАННА** для Адресата или несколько **МЕНЕЕ ОЧЕВИДНА**.

Градационные союзы: *не только... но и, не столько... сколько, скорее... чем, не то чтобы... (а), не то что... а, не сказать чтобы... но*.

Градационные союзы указывают на явное неравноправие и несимметричность (хотя и не противоречащих друг другу) конъюнктов и на то, что они соответствуют действительности в разной мере.

Союз *не только... но и* указывает на то, что оба конъюнкта соответствуют действительности, **в противоположность ожиданиям Адресата**, который, по мнению Говорящего, мог бы, исходя из своих знаний о мире или о конкретной ситуации, считать, что ей соответствует только первый.

4. **ВЫВОД**

В соответствии с данными определениями  следует считать, что второе утверждение (***и Базарову нравилась Фенечка***) менее очевидно для читателя и является для него неожиданностью.

Действительно, герой страдает от неразделенной любви к аристократической утонченной женщине, так что вряд ли он серьезно может в это время относиться к простушке Фенечке. Чем она могла прельстить его, кроме миловидной юности, чем воздействовать на его душу? И все-таки при ней он становился мягче, душевнее, добрее.

Отсюда следует **полная ясность нашего двойного союза НО И.**   Соединительное соответствие двух предложений (союз И) кажется читателю странным, и автор подчеркивает это противительным союзом НО.

Comment: Доброе утро, Александр, спасибо за правку. Написав этот второй ответ, я задумалась над его несовершенством.  И даже  вспомнила:  «Краткость нужна, чтобы мысль в словах не путалась  и ушей не терзала». Соответственно, ответ был приговорен к  немедленному уничтожению, ввиду отсутствия необходимой краткости. Но обстоятельства сему помешали…

Answer (score 0):

Значит, то, о чём сказано раньше, намекает на невзаимность, например что Фенечка глупая, некрасивая, толстая, бедная или т.п. Ну или, может, связано с тем, что Базарову нравился кто-то другой. Важно не то, что прочитают и смогут предположить обратное, а то, что это ожидание обусловлено информацией до этого.

Точка с запятой в данном случае употребляется для чёткости утверждения. Ну и как бы чтобы дать переварить информацию (скорее всего, неожиданную). При запятой мысль идёт дальше, как бы перемешиваясь со всем остальным, а здесь это не подходит. В данном случае точка с запятой почти точка, а не почти запятая.